# Google visualization combo chart aggregate tooltip

Tags: javascript, stack, tooltip, google-visualization

I have a sample google visualization combo chart in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aVVqr/) where the chart is draws as given below:

```
    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
    chart.draw(data, {
      title : 'Yearly Coffee Production by Country',
      width: 600,
      height: 400,
      vAxis: {title: "Cups"},
      hAxis: {title: "Month"},
      seriesType: "bars",
    isStacked: true,
    });
```

The above chart contain normal tooltip. But I am trying to format the tooltip as follows,

[image: tooltip]

when museovering on first stack and so on. What is the procedure to achieve it?

Comment: Depending on exactly what you want, you can either set the `focusTarget` option to `'category'` or you can use [custom tooltips](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content).

Comment: Yes..., I wanted same `focusTarget : 'category'`. See the edited [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aVVqr/1/). Thanks for the info.